# *** missing separator. Stop. Make file

Tags: makefile

i'm getting this error:

```
   make:24: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Although i changed all space character with tab in line 24.

Line24:arm_v5t_le-gcc $FILES $INCLUDES $LIBS -o $TARGET

Here is the code:

```
#DM_serial2_make

export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mv_pro_5.0/montavista/pro/devkit/arm/v5t_le/bin:/opt/mv_pro_5.0/montavista/pro/bin:/opt/mv_pro_5.0/montavista/common/bin" 
TARGET="/home/cilem/Desktop/06.05.2012/DM_serial2"

INCLUDES="  -I /home/cilem/Desktop/06.05.2012/libxml2 \
        -I /home/cilem/Desktop/06.05.2012/gstreamer-0.10  \
                -I /home/cilem/Desktop/06.05.2012/gstreamer-0.10/gst/interfaces \
                -I /home/cilem/Desktop/06.05.2012/glib-2.0 \
                -I /home/cilem/Desktop/06.05.2012/glib-2.0/include"

LIBS="  -L /home/cilem/Desktop/06.05.2012/lib/ -l:libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 \
    -L /home/cilem/Desktop/06.05.2012/lib/ -l:libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 \
    -L /home/cilem/Desktop/06.05.2012/lib/ -l:libgobject-2.0.so.0 \
    -L /home/cilem/Desktop/06.05.2012/lib/ -l:libgmodule-2.0.so.0 \
    -L /home/cilem/Desktop/06.05.2012/lib/ -l:libxml2.so.2 \
    -L /home/cilem/Desktop/06.05.2012/lib/ -l:libgthread-2.0.so.0 \
    -L /home/cilem/Desktop/06.05.2012/lib/ -l:libglib-2.0.so.0"


FILES="DM_serial2.c"

arm_v5t_le-gcc $FILES $INCLUDES $LIBS -o $TARGET
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a shell script.  Shell scripts are not makefiles, and vice versa.  You need to find a good tutorial on make, or read the GNU make manual.

For example, you should not have any quoting in your variable values.

Second, variable expansions in make require the variables to be surrounded by parens or curly braces: `$(FILES)` or `${FILES}`.

Third, as piokuc says, that line is not a valid make rule.  A make rule has the form:

```
<target> : <dependencies...>
        <commands...>
```

where the indentation of the `commands...` must be TAB characters.  This rule says "you can build `target` whenever it's older than any of `dependencies...` by running `commands...`".  The `target` and `dependencies` must (usually) be files, so you definitely don't want to use `$(INCLUDES)` or `$(LIBS)` in that list as those are compiler flags.

You probably want something like this, although it could be improved:

```
$(TARGET): $(FILES)
        arm_v5t_le-gcc $(FILES) $(INCLUDES) $(LIBS) -o $(TARGET)
```

You've got other weird things here.  You don't need to provide the same directory over and over with the `-L` flag.  Once is enough.  Also I'm not familiar with the `-l:libfoo.a` construct; usually it's just `-lfoo`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the last line should be replaced with something like:

```
$TARGET: $FILES $INCLUDES $LIBS
    arm_v5t_le-gcc $FILES $INCLUDES $LIBS -o $TARGET
```

The above line (the one starting with arm_v5t_le-gcc) should start with a tab, not spaces.